# Meaning of "take in the views"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I heard it in a game trailer where they used a sentence:

> Harvest resources and be on your way or simply take in the views.

I'm interested in knowing what can the "take in the views" mean. I couldn't find a result with Google search or even Bing search that showed something which they (the trailer) actually meant in my opinion.

One of the meaning Bing search showed was: “Simply take in the views” means “to understand completely the meaning or importance of something”.

When I used Google Translate and translated to my native language Hindi, it actually translated to something similar to "simply enjoy the scenes". Which seemed more relevant to the trailer.

But I couldn't find any reference in English for the same.

**So I want to know what else can this phrase mean (apart from the Bing definition)?**

Here are a few screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: "enjoy the scene" or "admire the landscape" are relevant.

Comment: We're much more likely to [*take in the **sights***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+in+the+sights%2Ctake+in+the+views&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) ("sightseeing" is an established leisure activity; "viewseeing" is just a weird combination). My first thought was your example text didn't come from a native Anglophone (which still might be true), but I suppose screenshots (or moving video clips) might be more naturally identified as "views" in the context of a video game trailer. I'd probably prefer ***screenshots***, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've updated it.

Comment: As other comments have said, it may not be quite idiomatic, but your Hindi translation is a pretty accurate version of the meaning, maybe "simply enjoy the *views*" would be better. If it's a video game then it really means "admire our beautiful artwork"

Comment: If the  things to be "taken in" are static ***screenshots*** (as opposed to dynamic ***video clips*** I suggest that's the word that should be used. But imho the construction ***take in the XXX's*** is a poor fit for this context, because it's so strongly associated with the ***sightseeing*** context as mentioned. ***Enjoy the screenshots*** would be much better.

Comment: Basically it's a video. Recorded gameplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *take something in* means to pause and consciously absorb the significance or beauty of something. It's most often used for complex and beautiful things like scenery, art, and music, but it can also be used for complex information like a policy directive, or something life-changing like a death in the family.

Merriam-Webster has this:

> **take in** *verb*
> **7 :** to receive into the mind : perceive
> *took in the view*

Some more natural examples:

> That presentation was a lot to take in. I'm going to have to review the slide deck.
> I just watched a movie about the Holocaust. I'm still taking it all in.